# Validating image uploads with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I have an image upload program setup that I made with PHP to allow the public to submit their images. I am having trouble finding a method to make sure the file is actually an image. I'm checking the file type, and also using getimagesize(), amongst other checks but if I rename a text file to become a JPG file my validation allows the file.  How can I ensure this is actually an image? I don't want my boss to execute any infected files.

Comment: When you are using getimagesize() make sure it returns a valid array with dimensions. Renaming your file to .txt will still preserve the actual headers of the file, a simple check of file extension will do just fine if that is your goal.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Imagick's identifyImage() command.
if it gives you back image data its an image if it hands back an error or no image data then its not an image. there is a command line version of this tool you can use to: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php if you do not have php compiled with imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

Check allowed extensions

.gif .jpg .jpeg .png should be allowed

Answer (score 0):

How about to use Exif module's exit-imagetype() function?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

```
<?php
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce the uploaded image using gd. If the image isn't reproduced, it's not an image!

If this function returns false, then it's not a valid image. I haven't worked with any more than jpg, png and gif, so there might be some more image types out there that can fit into this function (bmp?)...

```
function checkFileType($filetype,$tmp_name)
{
    $return_val = false;
    switch($filetype){
        case 'image/jpg':
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $return_val = @imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);
        break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $return_val = @imagecreatefromgif($tmp_name);
        break;
        case 'image/png':
        case 'image/x-png':
            $return_val = @imagecreatefrompng($tmp_name);
        break;
    }
    return $return_val;
}
```

Comment: You do this for a simple image check? Just use getimagesize() to determine if file is an actual image, the solution you provided is both slow and cluttered for what it does.